# Start-Process cannot find path on Z: drive when run from Ansible; works just fine locally

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 using Ansible for Windows and I'm running into a strange issue. The installer is located at `Z:\visualstudio\2017\vs2017_professional\vs2017_Professional.exe`, and here is my task to run it:

```
- name: Install Visual Studio
  win_shell: Start-Process -FilePath Z:\visualstudio\2017\vs2017_professional\vs2017_Professional.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet --norestart' -Wait
  args:
    creates: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.1\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  become_user: Administrator
```

However, it always fails:

> fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed":
>   true, "cmd": "Start-Process -FilePath
>   Z:\visualstudio\2017\vs2017_professional\vs2017_Professional.exe
>   -ArgumentList '--quiet --norestart' -Wait", "delta": "0:00:06.157773", "end": "2018-10-17 09:00:35.262158", "msg": "non-zero return code",
>   "rc": 1, "start": "2018-10-17 09:00:29.104384", "stderr":
>   "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The
>   system cannot find the drive specified.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ ...
>   ing $false; Start-Process -FilePath
>   Z:\visualstudio\2017\vs2017_profe ...\r\n+
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    +
>   CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process],
>   InvalidOperationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand",
>   "stderr_lines": ["Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to
>   the error: The system cannot find the drive specified.", "At line:1
>   char:65", "+ ... ing $false; Start-Process -FilePath
>   Z:\visualstudio\2017\vs2017_profe ...", "+
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "    +
>   CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process],
>   InvalidOperationException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand"],
>   "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

The file path is definitely valid, and *the exact same script* works just fine as a standalone powershell file run locally on the machine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you take the command you are trying to run in Ansible and just run from the (powershell or command) Prompt first does it work?

Comment: Is the `Z:` drive mapped/available for the account Ansible is running as?

Comment: Yes and yes (respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
- name: Install Visual Studio
  win_shell: Start-Process -FilePath " Z:\\visualstudio\\2017\\vs2017_professional\\vs2017_Professional.exe" -ArgumentList '--quiet --norestart' -Wait
  args:
    creates: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.1\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  become_user: Administrator
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?